# How can I create an alias for a network device?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I'm trying to get a particular piece of software to run that uses a licence manager that hasn't noticed that newer Linux distributions don't name their network devices `eth0` anymore. It is trying to verify the MAC address, but as my NIC is called `ens1` on Centos 7 this doesn't work.

The vendor of this software already fixed this on a different computer, and I'd like to understand how they did this. They created some kind of alias for `ens1` so that the licence manager can find `eth0` again.

The alias is not shown at all if I do `ifconfig -a`, but it is visible when explicitly calling `ifconfig eth0`. Using the `ip link` command it is visible as the following:

```
eth0@ens1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT
link/ether [mac address] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What exactly did they do here, and how can I recreate this kind of alias on another computer?

Comment: Did they perhaps use `ip link set ens1 name eth0@ens1`?  I doubt that would survive a reboot like that, but perhaps you can make the change in the `DEVICE` line in `ifcfg-ens1` or something?  Can you see both `eth0@ens1` and `ens1` in your `ip link` list, or just the new name?

Comment: i just tested this in a VM - `ip link set ens1 name eth0@ens1` shows the new name in `ifconfig -a` too.  and `ip link set ens1 alias eth0` shows `alias eth0` on a separate line when you run `ip link`.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably done using the `macvlan` feature.  It allows to add virtual Ethernet interfaces on top of an existing hardware interface.  In your case, it could have been done like this:

```
ip link add link ens1 name eth0 type macvlan
```

By default the new interface gets a randomly chosen locally administered unicast MAC address.  Alternatively you can specify the MAC address with `address <MAC>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a udev rule to rename the NIC back to the old `eth0` style.

e.g. edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to have a line like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is your NIC's MAC address.

You will also have to update any network configuration so that it uses the `eth0` name rather than `ens1`

See [Predictable Network Interface Names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) for more info on why this change has occurred.

Comment: I'd like to avoid completely renaming the interfaces, and I'm also curious just how the alias works that they implemented.

Comment: i've never seen that `eth0@ens1` form before, and googling for it only shows your question.  Have you tried `grep -r eth0 /etc`?  if you find it, please post as i'm curious too.