# Persistent network names using aliases, not renaming

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

How can I change persistent network names (e.g. `enx00b56d00d500`) to be aliases — not replacements — for the standard names given by Linux (`eth0`)?

I want to be able to use both names, but systemd.link currently destroys the original interface name with no obvious way to tell it not to.

#### Background

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux. I understand the benefits of persistent naming and want to continue using them, but have also found it frustrating that I can't rely on the simple Linux names working from the command line.

For example, some of my machines don't have any built-in ethernet and I have a dozen different USB to ethernet dongles on my workbench. I want whatever one I happen to plug in to be available as both `eth0` and as whatever persistent name systemd wants to give it.

I know from the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames) that I can disable network renaming by using the `net.ifnames=0` kernel parameter, but that page also states that it is *not* possible to create aliases such that one is free to use either name. I believe that may be old information since Linux has had [the capability to add alternative network names](https://lwn.net/ml/netdev/20190719110029.29466-1-jiri@resnulli.us/) since 2019.

Note that I do not wish to [manually rename the interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391535/how-to-add-an-alternative-name-for-the-interface). Ideally, a solution would prevent systemd from deleting the original name, but it would be fine if there was some automatic way to add the Linux name back as an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an alternative name for the interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391535/how-to-add-an-alternative-name-for-the-interface)

Comment: Thanks, @larsks, but that deals with manually adding alternative names. I've expanded my question to clarify that I am looking to automatically retain the original name when a persistent name is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Debian 11 (or later) you should already have the behavior you want. Automatic configuration of `altname` for interfaces is controlled by the [`AlternativeNamesPolicy`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#AlternativeNamesPolicy=) setting in `/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link`. With the default configuration:

```
[Match]
OriginalName=*

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep kernel database onboard slot path
AlternativeNamesPolicy=database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

If I boot a Debian 11 system with `net.ifnames=0`, I get:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:f7:e2:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eth0
```

And I can refer to this interface as either `enp1s0` or as `eth0`:

```
root@debian:~# ip -br link show eth0
enp1s0           UP             52:54:00:f7:e2:94 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
root@debian:~# ip -br link show enp1s0
enp1s0           UP             52:54:00:f7:e2:94 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

---

If you are running a version of Debian older than Debian 11, I think you may be out of luck: the `iproute` package on earlier distributions does not have `altname` support.

---

In response to your comment:

> Does Debian have a way to disable that (and any other `*.link` files that might be created in the future)?

You cannot disable "any other `*.link` files that might be created in the future", but you can disable or replace any specific file with an equivalently named file in `/etc/systemd/network` (this is true for any sort of systemd unit file). For the "disable" case, the easiest solution is to symlink the file to `/dev/null`; from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html:

> Files in /etc/ have the highest priority, files in /run/ take precedence over files with the same name in /usr/lib/. This can be used to override a system-supplied link file with a local file if needed. As a special case, an empty file (file size 0) or symlink with the same name pointing to /dev/null disables the configuration file entirely (it is "masked").

So you can mask the `73-usb-net-by-mac.link` file by running:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link
```

Comment: Oh! That would be lovely. Unfortunately, it appears that that behavior is overriden by `/usr/lib/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link`. Does Debian have a way to disable that (and any other *.link files that might be created in the future)?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but disabling 73-usb-net-by-mac.link doesn't work. Now my USB-to-Ethernet dongles show up with a different persistent name (enp3s0f3u1u1u4), but still no eth0. [I tried this on both Debian 11 (bullseye) and Debian 12 (bookworm). I have the same 99-default.link file as in your answer.]

Comment: I don't have handy a debian-based system into which I can plug a usb ethernet dongle. Does your interface have *any* altnames defined?

Comment: No, at least not according to `ip link show | grep alt`.